# How do I route traffic of one IP net to a different router using DD-WRT

Tags: vpn, routing, dd-wrt

I am running DD-WRT v3.0-r28211 std (11/16/15) on a router *behind* my actual internet router (which is a Fritz!Box).

The Set up is a follows:

- Internet router: `192.168.177.1` (Fritz).
- DD-WRT: `192.168.0.1` connection to `192.168.177.1` through the WAN Port.
- Sitecome Router (VPNConnection): `192.168.0.2` connection to `192.168.0.1` through the WAN Port (PPTP connection is already established for that router).

Is it possible to have the DD-WRT set up with routing information that all regular traffic is sent to `192.168.177.1` and only traffic regarding the IP Net of `66.*.*.*` is being routed through `192.168.0.2`?

My assumtion was that I have to change the setup somehow that `192.168.0.2` connects through its WAN Port to `192.168.177.1` but also has a connection to `192.168.0.1`.

Please be gentle with me I am still trying to dive into the depths of networking ;)

Thank you for your answers in advance,
Cheers & Happy New Years everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is called static routing. You add a new manual route in the routers Routing Table. [From the DD WRT manual](http://www.dd-wrt.com/help/english/HRouting.asp):

> Static Routing
>   A static route is a pre-determined pathway that network information must travel to reach a specific host or network.
>
> To set up a static route between the router and another network:
>   Select a number from the Static Routing drop-down list. Enter the following data:
>
> - Destination IP Address – The Destination IP Address is the address of
>     the network or host to which you want to assign a static route.
> - Subnet Mask – The Subnet Mask determines which portion of an IP address is the network portion, and which portion is the host portion.
> - Gateway – This is the IP address of the gateway device that allows for contact between the router and the network or host.
>
> Depending on where the Destination IP Address is located, select LAN & WLAN or WAN from the Interface drop-down menu. Click the Apply button to save your changes. To cancel your unsaved changes, click the Cancel button. For additional static routes, repeat steps 1-4.

This is done from the Advanced Routing page.

In your specific case, the subnet is /8, or 255.0.0.0. Gateway would be the VPN ip 192.168.0.2